# Error while sending a request to create a profile for a user

Tags: node.js, api, postman

I am building and API with nodejs express and postman and i am trying to send a request in postman but i get the following error in my console:

```
[ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client.
```

This is my code in my API where i have three routes one to get a profile, another to create/update profiles and another to get all profiles:

profile.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const auth = require('../../middleware/auth');
const Profile = require('../../models/Profile');
const User = require('../../models/User');
const {check, validationResult} = require('express-validator/');
const { route } = require('./users');

//@route   GET api/profile/me
//@desc    Get current users profile
//@access  private

router.get('/me', auth, async(req, res)=> {
    try{
        const profile = await Profile.findOne({user: req.user.id}).populate('user' ['name', 'avatar']);

        if(!profile){
            res.status(400).json({ msg: 'There is no profile for this user' });
        }

        res.json(profile);

    }catch(err){
        console.error(err.message);
        res.status(500).send('Server error');
    }
});

//@route   POST api/profile/
//@desc    Create or update a user profile
//@access  private

router.post(
  "/",
  [
    auth,
    [
      check("status", "Status is required").not().isEmpty(),
      check('skills', 'Skills is required').not().isEmpty()
    ]
],
  async (req, res) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if(!errors.isEmpty()){
        return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
    }

    const{
        company,
        website,
        location,
        bio,
        status,
        githubusername,
        skills,
        youtube,
        facebook,
        twitter,
        instagram,
        linkedin
    } = req.body;
 
    //Build profile objetc

    const profileFields = {};
    profileFields.user = req.user.id;
    
    if(company) profileFields.company = company;    
    if(website) profileFields.website = website;  
    if(location) profileFields.location = location;
    if(bio) profileFields.bio = bio;
    if(status) profileFields.bio;
    if(status) profileFields.status = status;
    if(githubusername) profileFields.githubusername = githubusername;
    if(skills){
        profileFields.skills = skills.split(',').map(skill =>skill.trim());
    }

    //Build social Object
    profileFields.social = {}
    if(youtube) profileFields.social.youtube = youtube;
    if(twitter) profileFields.social.twitter = twitter;
    if(facebook) profileFields.social.facebook = facebook;
    if(linkedin) profileFields.social.linkedin = linkedin;
    if(instagram) profileFields.social.instagram = instagram;

    try{
        let profile = await Profile.findOne({ user:req.user.id });
        if(profile){
            //Update existing profile
            profile = await Profile.findOneAndUpdate(
                { user:req.user.id },
                { $set:profileFields },
                { new:true }
            );

            return res.json(profile);
        }

        //Create
        profile = new Profile(profileFields);
        await profile.save();
        res.json(profile);

    }catch(err){
        console.error(err.message);
        res.status(500).send('Server error');
    }

  }
);

//@route   GET api/profile/
//@desc    Get all profiles
//@access  public

router.get('/', async(req,res)=>{
    try {
        const profiles = await Profile.find().populate('user', ['name', 'avatar']);
        res.json(profiles);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
        res.status(500).send('Server error');
    }
})


module.exports = router;
```

So the process is the following, with my routes i first create a user, then log the user in and i receive a token, later with that token i try to get the data of my logged in user through the route

```
http://localhost:5000/api/profile/me
```

And i get the message `There is no profile for this user` because i don´t have any created profile yet.

So i did a route for creating and updating the profile of a user.

```
http://localhost:5000/api/profile
```

Where the headers of this route are a `Content-type` with a value of `application/json`  and a `x-auth-token` with a value `the token of the logged in user`.

But when i send my request in postman i get the error `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5000`

I this error coming from my code?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `return` statement after sending the error response when there no profiles available:

```js
router.get('/me', auth, async(req, res)=> {
    try{
        const profile = await Profile.findOne({user: req.user.id}).populate('user' ['name', 'avatar']);

        if(!profile){
            res.status(400).json({ msg: 'There is no profile for this user' });
            return; // Stop execution here
        }

        res.json(profile);

    }catch(err){
        console.error(err.message);
        res.status(500).send('Server error');
    }
});
```